# How do you / Can you suggest column breaks?

Tags: formatting, two-column, multicol, multicolumn

I know that you can suggest a pagebreak with `\pagebreak[0..3]`, but is there an equivalent for suggesting a column break?

Comment: With twocolumn, use \pagebreak.  Obviously \columnbreak (multicol package) does not have an optional argument, but you can adjust the penalty manually.  \pagebreak uses \penalty 0, -\@lowpentalty -\@medpenatly or -\@highpenalty.

Comment: I might add that I have never found \pagebreak[3] to be of much use.  See the needspace package instead.

Answer (score 3):

In `multicol` a `\pagebreak` ends the collection of material for all columns (in contrast to what it does in twocolumn mode) which is why there is an explicit `\columnbreak` to force a break for just a single column.

However, normal non-forcing penalties will guide the breaking algorithm as usual when it cuts the collected material into columns, so that `\pagebreak[3]` etc is saying here is a good place to break. But as mentioned in a comment the default LaTeX values for such penalities are usually too small to make a difference when page breaking (they are more useful for linebreaking which has more flexibility).

In the example below multicol breaks at the `\pagebreak[3]` but if you replace the `\bigskip`s with `\medskip` then it already ignores the suggestion and you need something like `\penalty -9000` to make it break there (simply because the column doesn't have enough stretchable glue in it so a break looks bad to TeX an -300 is not enough to counter that).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

Some text for testing \par

\bigskip

Some text for testing \par

\bigskip

Some text for testing \par

\bigskip

Some text for testing \par


\pagebreak[3]
%\penalty -9000       % something like this need if \medskip is used above


\lipsum[2-5]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```